# Gson - Automatic quote (") escaping?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using GSON on my Java EE server to provide some json to views.
In some object, I have long text, that can contains anything (like 'What a "great" news!').

I'm supprised that by default GSON doesn't escape the double quote, so it doesn't generate a valid JSON.

Is there a good way of doing this ?

Comment: Does an escape character work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but I was able to get GSON to handle Strings with quotes without any settings or changes.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GSONTest {

    public String value;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        GSONTest gt = new GSONTest();
        gt.value = "This is a \"test\" of quoted strings";
        System.out.println("String: " + gt.value);
        System.out.println("JSON: " + g.toJson(gt));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
String: This is a "test" of quoted strings
JSON: {"value":"This is a \"test\" of quoted strings"}
```

Maybe I don't understand what you're asking?

Comment: +1 for providing an almost identical answer to mine a minute earlier :-)

Comment: Yeah sorry you are right !
With a request from my browser (typing url) I get the valid JSON.
But when I get the JSON with Javascript, with jQuery jsonP, escape symbols are removed ... This is really strange.

Comment: @Stéphane Piette: Aren't you viewing the string as read in by Javascript, i.e., after unescaping? IMHO the very fact that you were able to get the object in Javascript means it was correctly formed JSON.

Comment: You might need this code to handle double quote properly:
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

Comment: Thanks sunghun Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();  This line fix that.

Answer (score 14):

Try using setPrettyPrinting with DisableHtml escaping.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson; 

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
 JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
 JsonElement je = jp.parse(jsonArray.toString());
 System.out.println( gson.toJson(je));
```

Comment: Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
made it work in my typeconverter for LIst<String>. You saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: in my case just `disableHtmlEscaping()` was enough

Answer (score 9):

Here's some sample GSON code:

```
final JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
obj.addProperty("foo", "b\"a\"r");
System.out.println(obj.toString());
```

The Output is:

> {"foo":"b\"a\"r"}

(as it should be)

So either you are doing something wrong, or you are using an ancient version of GSON. Perhaps you should show some of your code?

Comment: @david.mihola don't worry, I'll survive. But thanks for telling me

Answer (score 9):

That is what I did to solve that

```
private final Gson mGson;
{
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new EscapeStringSerializer());
    mGson = builder.create();
}

private static class EscapeStringSerializer implements JsonSerializer<String> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(String s, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(escapeJS(s));
    }

    public static String escapeJS(String string) {
        String escapes[][] = new String[][]{
                {"\\", "\\\\"},
                {"\"", "\\\""},
                {"\n", "\\n"},
                {"\r", "\\r"},
                {"\b", "\\b"},
                {"\f", "\\f"},
                {"\t", "\\t"}
        };
        for (String[] esc : escapes) {
            string = string.replace(esc[0], esc[1]);
        }
        return string;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the last/5th replace is wrong. At least PostgreSQL 9.4 JSON-type doesn't accept an escaped single quote.

Comment: -1.The escapeJS() method will perform poorly for any large amount of data since escapeJS() must traverse the entire string `n` times, where `n` is the number of your replacement rules. This is better modeled with a simple DFA that goes over the string once, or just use a library.