# Adding JsonArray to JsonObject generated escape characters (gson)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I'm using [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to create a json object and add a json array to it. My code looks something like this:

```
JsonObject main = new JsonObject();
main.addProperty(KEY_A, a);
main.addProperty(KEY_B, b);

Gson gson = new Gson();
ArrayList<JsonObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
JsonObject objectInList = new JsonObject();
objectInList.addProperty(KEY_C, c);
objectInList.addProperty(KEY_D, d);
objectInList.addProperty(KEY_E, e);
list.add(objectInList);
main.addProperty(KEY_ARRAY,gson.toJson(list));
```

The output seems to contain some unexpected slashes:

```
{"A":"a","B":"b","array":["{\"C\":\"c\",\"D\":\"d\",\"E\":\"e\"}"]}
```

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813434/trouble-with-gson-serializing-an-arraylist-of-pojos) help you?
quoting: "You need to give Gson information on the specific generic type of List you're using (or any generic type you use with it)."

Comment: ```main.addProperty(KEY_ARRAY,gson.toJson(list,new TypeToken<List<JsonObject>>(){}.getType()));``` unfortunately made no difference

Comment: Hmm... Actually it seems to me that the slashes are for escaping  double quot character in the array values, since \" is the escape character for double quot in java and C.
Basically if you print the value in the output, it should just be fine. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258858/gson-automatic-quote-escaping).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you do:

```
main.addProperty(KEY_ARRAY, gson.toJson(list));
```

you add a key-value pair `String -> String` in your `JsonObject`, not a `String -> JsonArray[JsonObject]`.

Now you get this slashes because when Gson serialize this List into a String, it keeps the informations about the values in the json object in the array (that are Strings so the quotes need to be escaped via backslashes).

You could observe the same behavior by setting

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

then the output of the array is:

```
"array": "[\n  {\n    \"C\": \"c\",\n    \"D\": \"d\",\n    \"E\": \"e\"\n  }\n]"
```

But what you are looking for is to have the correct mapping, you need to use the `add` method and give a `JsonArray` as parameter. So change your `list` to be a `JsonArray`:

```
JsonArray list = new JsonArray();
```

and use `add` instead of `addProperty`:

`main.add("array", list);`

and you'll get as output:

```
{"A":"a","B":"b","array":[{"C":"c","D":"d","E":"e"}]}
```